# Reshape long to wide with multiple groupings

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

My data looks like this:

```
  Smoker PtNo Day Hour FEV1 timename
1       0    1   1    0 3.26     d1h0
2       0    1   1    2 3.05     d1h2
3       0    1   1    4 3.02     d1h4
4       0    1   1    6 3.27     d1h6
5       0    1   2    0 3.28     d2h0
6       0    1   2    2 3.07     d2h2
7       0    1   2    4 3.35     d2h4
8       0    1   2    6 3.07     d2h6
9       0    1   3    0 3.28     d3h0
10      0    1   3    2 3.44     d3h2
```

I want to reshape it into wide format like this:

```
PtNo  Smoker  FEV1.d1h0  FEV1.d1h2  FEV1d1.h3   etc.
```

Where PtNo and Smoker and independent variables not varying by time, and FEV1 is the measured time-varying variable. I get various error messages using `reshape` and the `melt`/`dcast` functions in the `reshape2` package. Any suggestions?  (Please tailor response to novice level.)

Comment: pls include code with dcast and errors it triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
reshape(dat,direction='wide',
        idvar=c('Smoker','PtNo'),
        v.names='FEV1',
        timevar='timename',
        drop=c('Day','Hour'))

 Smoker PtNo FEV1.d1h0 FEV1.d1h2 FEV1.d1h4 FEV1.d1h6 FEV1.d2h0 FEV1.d2h2 FEV1.d2h4 FEV1.d2h6 FEV1.d3h0 FEV1.d3h2
1      0    1      3.26      3.05      3.02      3.27      3.28      3.07      3.35      3.07      3.28      3.44
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> dcast(df, PtNo + Smoker ~ timename, value.var="FEV1")
 PtNo Smoker   d1h0 d1h2 d1h4 d1h6 d2h0 d2h2 d2h4 d2h6 d3h0 d3h2
1   1      0   3.26 3.05 3.02 3.27 3.28 3.07 3.35 3.07 3.28 3.44
```

If you want the col names to be exactly as you have them, then you can just `paste` "FEV1" to `timename` before you `dcast`.  `dcast` is from package `reshape2`.

Comment: Thank you.  Both solutions work well.  First solution seems straightforward to generalize to multiple types of measures taken at the same timepoints.